# How to post a list from view to controller mapped to viewModel in Asp.net core?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, controller, viewmodel

Here is my ViewModel

```
public class VideoViewModel
{
    public string Movie { get; set; }
    public int Order { get; set; }

    public IList<VideoContent> VideoContents { get; set; }
}
```

How can I pass data from fields in view to controller mapped to my collection in my viewModel?

This code in my view is passing Movie and Order to controller but I can't figure out hos to send the collection too.

```
@model ViewModels.VideoViewModel
    <form method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="movie">Movie</label>
            <input type="text" name="Movie" id="movie" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="order">Order</label>
            <input type="text" name="Order" id="order" class="form-control">
        </div>            
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add to database</button>
    </form>
```

Thanks in advance!

/ Kalle

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ASP .NET Core uses the name attribute to bind the data from the input fields to the view model.

This should work for passing the collection.

```
for(int c = 0; c < VideoContents.Count; c++)
{      
    <input name="VideoContents[@c].FirstProperty" value="@Model.VideoContents[@c].FirstProperty"/>
    <input name="VideoContents[@c].SecondProperty" value="@Model.VideoContents[c].SecondProperty"/>
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! You have saved my day :-)